# Creating templates for authentication forms in Django 1.7

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-authentication, django-1.7

First off, I'm very much a newbie when it comes to Django.

The problem I'm struggling with is in trying to create templates for the built-in authentication forms in Django 1.7 but there is very little that I can find in the way of concrete examples anywhere in the documentation or elsewhere.

I can find plenty of questions and examples that describe how to manually create the templates (or copy them from the Django packages) but from what I understand about the Form class and the built-in authentication forms is that I don't need to manually create the actual form in the template. In fact, it seems more desirable to use the Form classes because that would add ensure that fields are named correctly, that the validation such as max length on text fields is applied, etc.

Can anyone point me to some concrete examples or documentation of what I'm talking about? I've read the following sections already,

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/

In fact, I would say that this question extends to any Form class in general but I'm specifically looking at the authentication forms here because I obviously haven't written these Form classes.

I don't think it should make any difference from what I've read since the same process should apply, but I will say that I'm using the django-authtools package (http://django-authtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

I have the actual authentication system working fine. It logs users in and out, I can enforce that certain urls require the user to be logged in first, etc. so its only the actual form display that is an issue.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are having problems with. The forms documentation you link to show exactly how to use forms in templates and views: what, precisely, are you confused about, and what, exactly, do you want us to help with?